# SQL NOT IN clause not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Im trying to get a list of names that do not exist in another list

```
    SELECT [Paid To]
    FROM tbl1
    WHERE [Paid To] not  in
    (select [Name ] 
    FROM tbl2
    )
```

I dont get any results
but when I run a left join query

```
select top 10 *
from [tbl1] a
left join [tbl2] b
on a.[Paid To] = b.[Name ]
```

I get the NULLs where the 2 tables dont match.
Can anyone help as to why the first query is not working?

using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Are you trying to compare name with id ??? i think that is the reason

Comment: Do you have any rows in `tbl2` where `[Name ]` is `NULL`?

Comment: @smn_onrocks = no, they are both names

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - YES, why does that matter?

Comment: Because of three-valued logic. See the question I've linked to.